# xml file parsing

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-parsing

How can I add/alter to my code so once if extracts out the values of the max/min it compare the extracted value to a set value and writes out pass/fail. For example: xmax extracts out and it is 280 and I have a condition in my code saying that xmax needs to be less than 275 so write out fail. This needs to be done for each max/min.Any Ideas...? I used linq to xml to parse but is their a better way?

```
var query = from file in fileEntries
                        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
                        let x = doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib").Single()
                        let y = doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib").Single()
                        let z = doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib").Single()
                        select new 
                       {

                            XMax = x.Element("Max").Value,
                            XMin = x.Element("Min").Value,
                            YMax = y.Element("Max").Value,
                            YMin = y.Element("Min").Value,
                            ZMax = z.Element("Max").Value,
                            ZMin = z.Element("Min").Value
                        };
```

Comment: Instead of using Single you should use First. In fact Single check if the value is unique so it takes more time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
var results = from item in query
              select new 
              {
                   XMaxResult = item.XMax < 275 ? "pass" : "fail",
                   ...
              };
```

Comment: Is this code suppose to be another query. How does it compare the value extracted to the set value? Where does it right out pass/fail

Comment: @Casey yes it's another query that uses the results of the query that you already have. Think of the results of your query as a set of rows, each with {XMax, XMin, YMax, ...}. Now this second query iterates through each of the rows and checks some condition against each property to write out pass/fail tot XMaxResult, YMaxResult ... so on.

Comment: @Casey: If you want to throw an exception to indicate failure, rather than simply mark pass/failure as flags, Linq isn't going to directly help you.  Linq can only iterate, filter, and transform - it isn't designed to support side-effects during enumeration.  While this won't prevent you from writing code that has side-effects, it will be a dirty hack (e.g. deliberately throwing in a lambda passed to the `Select` method).  The less hackish way to handle this is to iterate over the enumeration you built with Linq (`foreach`), see if a failure flag is set, and throw an exception if it is.

Comment: i get an error that says operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type string or int. Am i inputting something wrong?

Comment: @Casey oh ya. try  `XMaxResult = Convert.ToInt32(item.XMax) < 275 ? "pass" : "fail",`

Comment: that works and builds no errors but no pass or fail display on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an XML schema for this.

It will let you build your C# so that it takes just a few lines of code to check the document both for structural correctness, and semantic correctness.  It is also something you can publish separately from your app so that users can understand how documents should be laid out.  Some XML editors support schemas, too, so they might get some sort of automatic syntactical support/checking in their editor.

Here is how you would check a maximum value in an XSD schema:

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp

```
...

<xs:element name="Max">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <!-- Must be less than 275 -->
      <xs:maxInclusive value="274"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

...
```

Comment: If you look into XSD schemas and find them lacking, you can also look into using [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Extension Method to check the value

```
public static class Test {
static int check(this XElement element)
{
    if(element.Value < 100 || element.Value > 275)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    return element.Value;
}
}
```

Then you can do

```
select new 
{
    XMax = x.Element("Max").Check(),
    XMin = x.Element("Min").Check(),
    YMax = y.Element("Max").Check(),
    YMin = y.Element("Min").Check(),
    ZMax = z.Element("Max").Check(),
    ZMin = z.Element("Min").Check()
};
```

Comment: how does the extension method work. I'm not seeing how it works clearly and how the structure of the complete code will look.